# How to use a FilledButton in flutter (Material 3)

Tags: flutter, material3

[image]

link1 (Screenshot) : https://flutter.github.io/samples/web/material_3_demo/#/

link2 (Document) : https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/FilledButton-class.html#material.FilledButton.1

- flutter doctor

  [✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.3.10, on macOS 12.5.1 21G83 darwin-arm, locale ko-KR)
  • Flutter version 3.3.10 on channel stable at /Users/username/development/flutter
  • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
  • Framework revision 135454af32 (8 days ago), 2022-12-15 07:36:55 -0800
  • Engine revision 3316dd8728
  • Dart version 2.18.6
  • DevTools version 2.15.0

I want use filled button

I try import material package like the official document code, But FilledButton class could not be found.

This widget not yet implemented?

---

[Edited]

I found a way to use FilledButton

[In terminal...]

```
flutter channel master
flutter pub upgrade
```

Then, Can find FilledButton class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is not implemented yet, but you can build it with `ElevatedButton` like this:

```
ElevatedButton(
    onPressed: () {},
    child: Text("Filled"),
    style: ButtonStyle(
      minimumSize: MaterialStateProperty.all(Size(130, 40)),
      elevation: MaterialStateProperty.all(0),
      shape: MaterialStateProperty.all<RoundedRectangleBorder>(
        RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The M3 buttons are now available on flutter, FilledButton and FilledButton.tonal

```
FilledButton.tonal(
   onPressed: () {},
   child: const Text('Enabled'),
)
```

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/FilledButton-class.html

Answer (score 0):

there isn't any filled button in flutter you can use ElevatedButton to get like this button

```
 ElevatedButton(onPressed: () {}, child: Text("Elevated Button")),
```

Comment: flutter have three types of button ElevatedButton,TextButton,OutlinedButton about which you can learn more in the doc https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/widgets/material

Comment: There is actually FilledButton and even the .tonal option with latest Flutter version  https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/FilledButton-class.html

Answer (score 0):

This repository contains the official demo.

Use an emulator to determine which M3 button corresponds to the Flutter.
In your case, the FilledButton is an ElevatedButton with specific properties. (note: the 0 elevation)

https://github.com/BoltUIX/Flutter-material-design-3

```
    ElevatedButton(
      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
        foregroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onPrimary, backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary,
      ).copyWith(elevation: ButtonStyleButton.allOrNull(0.0)),
      onPressed: () {  },
      child: const Text('Filled'),
    ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Sample code they use to get those buttons:

```
        ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: isDisabled ? null : () {},
          child: const Text('Elevated'),
        ),
        colDivider,
        FilledButton(
          onPressed: isDisabled ? null : () {},
          child: const Text('Filled'),
        ),
        colDivider,
        FilledButton.tonal(
          onPressed: isDisabled ? null : () {},
          child: const Text('Filled tonal'),
        ),
        colDivider,
        OutlinedButton(
          onPressed: isDisabled ? null : () {},
          child: const Text('Outlined'),
        ),
        colDivider,
        TextButton(
          onPressed: isDisabled ? null : () {},
          child: const Text('Text'),
        ),
```

you could found more detail [here](https://github.com/flutter/samples/blob/main/material_3_demo/lib/component_screen.dart)